# PHP - Return an array key based on a hash

Tags: php

Given a N-bit hash (e.g. output of md5()), I have 2 situations I need solutions for:

1. Based on the hash, return an integer value in a given range.
2. Based on the hash, return an array value from a given array.

Same hash, should always return same number or array key within that range or from that same input array. If the input array changes but hash remains the same, then i would get a different selection.

So for example i would have code like this:

```
    echo intFromHash(1, 100, 'abcd'); // 15
    echo intFromHash(1, 100, 'defg'); // 90
    echo arrayValueFromHash(['moe', 'joe', 'pike'], 'abcd'); // 'joe'
    echo arrayValueFromHash(['pike', 'dolly']); // pike
```

Comment: can you provide any code from your current "intFromHash" and "arrayValueFromHash" functions?

Comment: @FalcoB there's no code, those are actually the functions I need.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples, provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure a similar question wasn't already answered. Please also note that [so] is not a coding service. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help.

Comment: You can write `intFromHash()` in 1 line of code using the [`crc32()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) PHP function. Then you can use it to implement `arrayValueFromHash()` (in another line of code).

Answer (score 1):

You can write `intFromHash()` in 1 line of code using the [`crc32()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) PHP function:

```
function intFromHash($min, $max, $hash {
    return $min + crc32($hash) % ($max - $min + 1);
}
```

Use `abs(crc32($hash))` if you are running it on a 32-bit system (read the documentation for details).

Then you can use it to implement `arrayValueFromHash()` (in another line of code):

```
function arrayValueFromHash(array $array, $hash) {
    return $array[intFromHash(0, count($array) - 1, $hash)];
}
```

Use `return $array[array_keys($array)[intFromHash(...)]];` if `$array` is an associative array (the expression presented in the code works only for numerically indexed arrays, as those listed in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out I think. Here's the code for whoever needs it:

```
    /**
     * Return a key from an array based on a given 4-bit hash.
     *
     * @param array $array Array to return a key from.
     * @param string $hash 4-bit hash. If hash is longer than 4-bit only first 4 bits will be used.
     * @return mixed
     */
    function getArrayValueByHash($array, $hash)
    {
        $arrayKeys = array_keys($array);
        $index = getIntFromHash(0, sizeof($arrayKeys)-1, $hash);
        return $array[$arrayKeys[$index]];
    }

    /**
     * Return an integer in range, based on a hash.
     *
     * @param int $start
     * @param int $end
     * @param string $hash 4-bit hash. If hash is longer than 4-bit only first 4 bits will be used.
     * @return int
     */
    function getIntFromHash($start, $end, $hash)
    {
        $size = $end-$start;
        $hash = str_split($hash);
        $intHash = ord($hash[0]) * 16777216 + ord($hash[1]) * 65536 + ord($hash[2]) * 256 + ord($hash[3]);
        $fits = $intHash / $size;
        $decimals = $fits - floor($fits);
        $index = floor($decimals * $size);
        return $start+$index;
    }
```

Comment: I believe you meant "4-byte" not "4-bit".